# Unstable selection behavior WebView Android according to platform version

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

This is kinda strange but I'm wondering if some one faced this and had this problem solved.

We are developing a book reader app in Android and we use WebView as the key player there. Our main problem is the text selection in web view. It works on some platform versions, but  not on others.

Some of the strange behaviors we faced:

1. When you select, nothing got selected
2. When you select a line, the line above it got selected, not the one you are on
3. when you select a line and try to expand new selection behavior starts

Solving one problem of them may work in the device you test on but not on another one. Devices in different brands (and more specifically different API levels) may or may not have some of the previous problems. API levels may differ in something like Android 4.1.1 and 4.1.2 and you get different behavior.